# How to get Details on NullPointerException in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, nullpointerexception

I am getting a null pointer exception in jsp and I want to find out what line has the null variable so i can fix it. Is there any simple way to do this? The printStackTrace didn't seem to give me any relevant information.

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at org.apache.jsp.data.index2_jsp._jspService(index2_jsp.java:176) 
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802) 
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331) 
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329) 
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802) 
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) 
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:244) 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:537) 
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:276) 
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:262) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:171) 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213) 
    at org.apache.catalina.co
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) 
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117) 
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:420)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Comment: You should edit your question to include output of the stack trace

Answer (score 7):

It's not pretty but you could go into the work directory and find the specified Java file (the converted JSP) and see what operations are on the specified line. Generally Tomcat will keep the source for the generated servlet around unless configured not to. It should at least help you find the error-point or the corresponding JSP line.

Hope this helps.